# accessing map elements increase it's allocated memory size

Tags: c++, memory-management, dictionary

I have a `map<vector<double>,double>` element in my code named `EU`.

I have noticed that the memory usage by my code tends to accumulate until I have used the entire available memory on my machine (going from ~200 MB to ~ 4GB). commenting out stuff in my code I have come to the conclusion that a line that access an element in this map is the one that, one commented out, prevent the memory usage increase. 
I access the value using []operator and I thought that this might be because the double values are not exactly the same as those in the map. I then searched for a case where this might be:

```
std::map<vector<double>,double>::iterator mit = EU.find(s);     
if (mit == EU.end()){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    O.w(s[i]);
  }
  cin.ignore();
}
```

Here `O.w(s[i])` is a function In I class I have created to display stuff on screen/write to hard disk. In this case it is simply `printf("%0.10f\n",s[i])` and I use `cin.ignore()` just to stop the program so I could check the output. 
Which also cause the increase in memory usage. 
Why is that so and how can I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry - on rereading I have real trouble understanding what you are asking/what the code does. Would you mind posting the real code/more code? This is way underspecified. (`O.w(s[i])` means virtually nothing there, and `cin.ignore()` without any input shown is more or less ridiculous)

Comment: I have edited the code. I'm not really sure what I am asking my self. I have noticed a constant increase in memory consumption which I have found that happens due to the [] operator and I try to figure this out

Comment: I don't see anything in this particular code that would hog memory. Vector's operator `[]` does not do anything bad. Map.find() doesn't do anything bad. If there's a problem, it would be elsewhere (you may be right that doubles as key are bad, but then again, would it be that bad?)

Comment: I think I have figured that out, and double as a key is that bad because I can't compare stuff completely. I'll need to change that to integer but that will take me some time... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access an element in a `std::map`, if the index has no associate value then a new element is created. So each time you access the map with a new key a new node is created to hold both the new `std::vector< double >` key and `double` value.

Comment: *"I thought operator < was not defined for standard sequences"* -- It is, as a free function, it simply does a lexicographical compare.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I see it in the C++11 standard, was it always this way?

Comment: "When you access an element" when you access it using the `[]` operator, that is. Not when you use `find()` or iterate through the elements.